# Installing Visual Studio 2017 Behind Corporate Proxy

Tags: proxy, ntlm, visual-studio-2017

Pretty simple problem. I'm unable to install VS 2017 RC behind an NTLM corporate proxy. I have tried running it through fiddler and fiddler + cntlm with no luck.

I have also tried creating .exe.config files for the outer (vs_enterprise.exe) and inner (vs_setup_bootstrapper, vs_installer and vs_installershell) files.

In all cases it doesn't look like the installer is trying to connect anywhere and in the few cases when it does connect, even when it gets a '200' with some data I still get a "You may not be connected to a network" error.

I'm sure that fiddler and cntlm are both working as I use them for my node/npm tools.

I don't have any 'safe' machines outside the firewall so I can't create the download there and pull it here.

Can anybody suggest any other ways of installing the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MS have addressed the proxy issue.Problem solved.

From the comments:
`The installer now uses auto-proxy detection for downloads.` from release notes of version 15.4 preview 2, September 11, 2017.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes

Comment: Uh?! Can you elaborate?

Comment: What I mean was I was able to download and run the installer and install visual studio behind my corporate proxy now. No fiddler or anything, just straight download, run and install. I have done this with VS2017 15.0 and the 15.1 (preview versions) have them running side by side with no installation issues. No proxy changes were made.

Comment: Did you include the mobile development in your install? I can install other components but somehow the mobile development component still requires a proxy to download some java sdk.

Comment: No, only did web stack, azure, node js and .net core

Comment: `The installer now uses auto-proxy detection for downloads.` from release notes of version 15.4 preview 2, September 11, 2017. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-preview-relnotes

Comment: [Proxy Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/proxy-configuration)

Answer (score 10):

if you add

```
<system.net>
   <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
   </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

to the bottom of your machine.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config and Framework64 then this should fix it. Also fixed my problems syncing to VSTS

Answer (score 6):

The I3enners answer is correct but if you are behinde a company proxy probrably you need to add user,password and domain on the proxy addess like this:

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">  
    <proxy bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://domain%5Cusername:password@youproxyaddress:portnumber" />
  </defaultProxy> 
</system.net>
```

The '%5C' is the excape for '' .
Put the code to the bottom of your machine.config in

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config`

Comment: This solution worked for me in my web.config files (where I found existing <system.net> elements) in the same directories.  I was downloading extra modules after the initial install.